# How to limit AWS Lex slot prompt retries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created an AWS Lex chatbot. In the intent, I created a built-in slot with a prompt. When the slot don't get expected value it asks for the input again and again. I want to limit the slot prompts. e.g. When slot don't get expected input it should stop asking the same slot value.

In the documentation, AWS says, by default maxAttemps attribute is set to 2. But it didn't work, it keeps sending the slot prompt. Is there any reason why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Lex V1 or V2?

V2 has a maximum of 5 retries.

Have you ensured that you've explicitly set and saved this against the slot in question and that you've correctly rebuilt the bot after saving the setting?